# Proving that shortest path distance of adjacent nodes can't differ by more than one

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

Could someone explain this proof to the following question?

> Lemma 22.1 from intro to algorithms
>
> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed or undirected graph, and let $s\in V$ be any vertex. Then, for any edge $(u,v)\in E$,
>
> $$\mathrm{dist}(s,v)\leq \mathrm{dist}(s,u)+1\,.$$
> *Proof.*
> If $u$ is reachable from $s$, then so is $v$. In this case, the shortest path from $s$ to $v$ cannot be longer than the shortest path from $s$ to $u$ followed by the edge $(u,v)$ and thus the inequality holds.

I drew this to visualize the problem but I don't see how what I drew is wrong and how the proof is correct.

[image]

If going from $s$ to $u$ has less vertices along that path than going from $s$ to $v$, than the shortest distance of $s$ to $v$ should be greater than going from $s$ to $u$ and $s$ to $u$ to $v$.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: Assume the opposite, i.e. the difference is greater than one. What can you conclude?

Comment: What is "intro to algorithms"; the book by CLRS?

Comment: I don't think the proof is correct at all - it merely restates the theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your diagram but the point is that, if there is a $x$–$y$ path of length $k$ then the distance from $x$ to $y$ cannot be bigger than $k$.

So, suppose the shortest path<sup>1</sup> $P$ from $s$ to $v$ has length $k$. If that path includes $u$, then there is a path of length less than $k$ from $s$ to $u$. Since there is a path of length less than $k$, the distance from $u$ to $v$ is less than $k$, so it is less than or equal to $k+1$, as required.  On the other hand, if $P$ does not include $u$, then $P$ followed by the edge $uv$ is a path from $s$ to $v$ of length $k+1$. Since there is a path of length $k+1$, the shortest path can't be longer than that, so the distance is at most $k+1$.

<sup>1</sup> I should really say "a shortest path", since there can be multiple different paths, all of the same length.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the shortest path between $s$ and $u$, and suppose it has $n$ edges.
Then append one edge to the path, which is $(u,v)$. We get *a* path from $s$ to $v$, of length $n+1$.

By definition, the length of the *shortest* path between $s$ and $v$ is not greater than $n+1$, which is the length of some path between $s$ an $v$.

Makes sense?

Comment: Didn't I already say all of that in my answer? Except that I was careful to deal with the case that $v$ is already on the shortest $s$-$u$ path $P$ since, in that case, you can't add the edge $uv$ to the path $P$ and call it "a path between $s$ and $v$" since the "path" contains a cycle.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Given the time difference between posting the two answers, they have likely started typing before your answer appeared.

Comment: I think this answer is clearer: it leaves out unnecessary detail. However, the question was not to come up with a proof but what is wrong with the given 'proof'.

Comment: adding to the answer: the thing that's wrong with the drawing is the path between $s$ and $v$ of length $5$. This is obviously not the *shortest* path, because the path $s-u-v$ is of length $3$. And this is exactly what the lemma is about.